# How do I refresh auto margins when I resize an element using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a DIV in the center of my page which has margin-left and margin-right both set to auto. I want to be able to enlarge or shrink that DIV. Unfortunately when I do so, the position of it on the screen does not change, meaning that it is no longer centered.

```
<div id="content" style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;width:240px">
  <p>Lots of text</p>
</div>
```

Meanwhile elsewhere:

```
$("#content").width(480);
```

At this point, I get my div no longer centered, but overbalanced to the right. Similarly if I set the width smaller than 240, it then becomes too far to the left.

How do I ensure that my margins actually adjust when the width changes? Needs to work in all modern browsers.

Comment: I've worked out a way of doing this now. I do something like the following: margin = $(window).width() / 2 - $("#content").width() / 2; $("#content").css("margin-left",margin + "px");

Comment: Actually, my solution is not a good one as it's not a true auto margin. If you then resize the window, the DIV will not stay centered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The div ist still centered. Just the text is aligned left.

Try this:

```
<div id="content" style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;width:240px;border:1px solid red;text-align:center">
  <p>Click here</p>
```

```
$('p').click(function(){$("#content").width(480)})
```

-
http://jsfiddle.net/nvzaw/1/

Comment: I'm sorry. I gave a bad exmaple. My DIV had some styling on it which changed the background so I could see that it was actually misalligned. I've actually worked this out now. I'll post an update. Sorry. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

I have posted an answer to a similar problem (about window resize) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9080561/925058)

Maybe this helps you!